# This question is related to android studio RecyclerView problem

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

when I download RecyclerView in my activity_main and when I try to code regarding it.
Then in it I want to import RecyclerView by extending the MyAdapter class that I made in Adapter named package,actually I wanted to extend RecyclerView through the code below(I want the below code to appear when I extend RecyclerView)

```
package Adapter;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< MyAdapter.ViewHolder >{

}
```

but due to suggetion the following code appears by default :

```
package Adapter;

public class MyAdapter extends AlertController.RecyclerListView.Adapter< MyAdapter.ViewHolder >
{

}
```

Note : here ViewHolder is the class that I wanted to make further in different class of different package.

Here I just wanted to extend RecyclerView((that was shown in the udemy course) instead of RecyclerListView  but when I try to extend RecyclerView by default option of RecyclerListView comes and also due to which AlertController comes in redletter means it shows that there is some error in it and this was not shown in udemy course and when I click on AlertController then it shows the message 
" 'androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController' is not public in 'andoridx.apppcompat.app'.Cannot be accessed from outside package "

and this AlertController thing is not shown in udemy course and this is causing hindrance in the further process such that I want to implement some methods but when I select public and try to implement some methods that was shown in the course but it doesn't work here in my code and as a result methods doesn't implement here in my code due to which I am unable to write further code.
so how can I solve this problem.I hope this makes you to understand the problem .Plz reply as soon as possible.

Comment: What did you mean by downloading the RecyclerView to your activity_main? did you add recycler view dependency in your app build.gradle file?

Comment: Downvote for stupid title. The tags already tell us that. The title should embody the actual question. If you want it answered by subject experts, that is.

Comment: Actually I was not known that was happening with me that's why given that title to the ques.

Comment: Thankyou sir for solving the problem @Shalan93

Comment: @DishaNamdev anytime

Comment: Bad title. Please ask @Shalan93 to post an answer to check it as correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused and I don't know what the issue is, but you missed () at the end

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< MyAdapter.ViewHolder >{

}
```

Should be:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

}
```

Comment: Ok, It was just by mistake and I have got the solution for the problem, thanku for answering @TomMat